# How to automatically assign node IP to NGINX ingress controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

I have a single-node k8s cluster on DigitalOcean. I used to use NGINX Ingress Controller with ClusterIP service, but then it stopped working for some reason, so I updated it to use LoadBalancer service instead, but it costs me $12, which is too much for my pet projects.

So as a temporary measure I am using NodePort service with a hardcoded external IP of the machine. Here's how the helm release configuration looks now:

```yaml
controller:
  enableExternalDNS: true
  service:
    externalIPs:
      - 46.XXX.XXX.XXX
    type: NodePort
rbac:
  create: true
```

But I don't like it being hardcoded like that. Is there a way to tell NGINX Ingress Controller to use node external IP without hardcoding it?
Or maybe there's some other way to expose the service without using LoadBalancer?

Comment: Do you need to directly specify the external IP address in your deployment configuration?  Does the Ingress setup need to know it at all?  A NodePort Service will be reachable on every node from outside the cluster, so as long as an out-of-cluster caller knows some node's IP address or DNS name, it should be able to reach the service; the Service itself shouldn't need to be told about the address.

Comment: If I don't specify the external IP, then DNS records start pointing to the cluster IP instead of the node IP.